# How to fetch the RecordTypeName Dynamically from the schema

Tags: apex, salesforce-lightning

Can anyone share the solution that 'How to fetch the RecordTypeName Dynamically from the schema' to store into custom object.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below syntax to fetch RecordTypeName dynamically from schema by giving custom ObjectName from which you want to fetch the recordTypeNames.
Further you can save this recordTypeNames in a custom field of your custom object.

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objDesc = ObjectName.SObjectType.getDescribe();
List<Schema.RecordTypeInfo> objRTList = objDesc.getRecordTypeInfos();  
for(Schema.RecordTypeInfo recType : objRTList) {  
system.debug(recType.getName());   
}
```

If you find it helpful, Please mark it as best answer.
Thanks